# What type of pattern does this JS adhere to?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I came across code similar to this recently,

```
// Simplified example..
var Application = 
    {
        MemberVar1: null,
        MemberVar2: null,

        Initialize: function ()
        {
            Application.MemberVar1 = 'Foo';
            Application.MemberVar2 = 'Bar';

            console.log("Initializing..");

            Application.GetMemberVars();
        },
        GetMemberVars: function ()
        {
            console.log(Application.MemberVar1 + ' ' + Application.MemberVar2);    
        }
    };

$(Application.Initialize);
```

What is the name of this pattern/method/style? Utilizing OOP principles without using a style I've seen before, such as prototyping. What are the benefits of this style as opposed to other popular ones?

Comment: this is one of the most common ways to use OOP...

Comment: It's a Singleton (achieved with an object literal).

Comment: Really? After researching JS OOP, I always came across using prototype or declaring variables that call a function with everything encapsulated within a function. However, the variable defines an object `{}`, as opposed to a function that I typically see, such that `var App = function Name() { }`

Comment: the function thing you're referring to is creating _constructors_, this is just an elaborate object literal, nothing more... honest :)

Comment: The functions you mention would be the classes, while the instances are objects created with `new FunctionName()`. In case of classes that require a single instance, an object literal is just simpler.

Comment: @bvaaretto - That makes even more sense now to me now (Singleton achieved with an object literal)

Comment: @Josh It looks to be a an [example of namespacing](http://addyosmani.com/blog/essential-js-namespacing/). They can be useful for keeping your objects and functions organized, as well as primarily out of the global scope to avoid cluttering and collisions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a simple one-off object literal that's being created... they can contain functions... perhaps that's what threw you.

The last line merely passes the `Application.Initialize` function to jQuery as a `$(document).ready` callback function

In light of the comments below, this is what the code actually does (and how you can write it a lot shorter/easier)

```
$(function()
{
    console.log("Initializing..");
    console.log("Foo Bar");//replace this with variables you declare @top of anon. function if you want
});
```

As a module (you can find out more about the module pattern [here](http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Module-Pattern-In-Depth.html)):

```
var Application = (function()
{
    var memberVar1, memberVar2,
    getMemberVars = function()
    {
        return memberVar1 + ' ' + memberVar2;
    };
    return {init: function()
    {
        memberVar1 = 'Foo';
        memberVar2 = 'Bar';
        console.log('initializing...');
        console.log(getMemberVars());
    }};
}());
$(Application.init);
```

`Application` is now an object literal, with only 1 property (`init`): a function that, because it was declared within the scope of that IIFE, has access to all variables local to that scope. That's the magic of closures for you. You can easily add getters and setters for the member vars, too:

```
var Application = (function()
{
    var memberVars = {},//turned into object literal...
    getMemberVars = function(all)
    {
        var i;
        if(typeof all === 'string' || typeof all === 'number')
        {
            return memberVars[all];
        }
        all = [];
        for (i in memberVars)
        {
            if (memberVars.hasOwnProperty(i))
            {
                all.push(memberVars[i]);
            }
        }
        return all;//or all.join(' '), as you please
    },
    get = function(name)
    {

        return typeof name === 'undefined' ? name : memberVars[name]; 
    },
    set = function(name, val)
    {
        memberVars[name] = val;
    };
    return {init: function()
    {
        memberVars.one = 'Foo';
        memberVars.two = 'Bar';
        console.log('initializing...');
        console.log(getMemberVars().join(' '));
    },
    get: get,
    set: set};//just add getter and setter here
}());
```

Comment: +1 Thank you. Is this standard practice? I understood how it all works, but actually haven't seen it before.

Comment: @Josh: this is a bit too elaborate to my personal taste as far as object literals go, but I'm a sucker for the module pattern, so who am I to say this isn't standard practice... I have come across this a few times... come to think of it, perhaps even more than _good_ prototype usage (but I am quite picky when it comes to good JS)

Comment: I'm sorry, are you saying this is common, but not necessarily *good* JS?

Comment: I haven't seen if often enough to say it's common, but I would definitely say it's not _good_ JS.

Comment: To both Scott and Elias, considering that this code is applied to UI controls for just *that page*, would it be appropriate to use this pattern?

Comment: @Josh: Object literals are very common (of course), sometimes assigning functions to properties of object literals is, too (module pattern, exposing closures using an object... ) but this snippet is not very good, no.

Comment: @josh: No, certainly not... if you want my honest opinion. I mean, really: a closure is a far better fit. Also, assigning `Initialize` to an object makes no sense at all. By passing a reference to that function to jQuery, the call context will never be that of `Application` you might as well pass an anonymous function to jQuery and take it from there

Comment: @Josh, ditto Elias.  There are many simpler ways of doing this.

Comment: Thank you both. Not only did you answer my OP, but educated me as well.  I appreciate it.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem I might've been unclear. Let's say a page included several UI controls with some creative interactions between them. Would this pattern, the module patern, be suitable and considered good practice to handle these interactions?

Comment: @Josh: this isn't the module pattern. My latest update was just about the snippet, I know your code does more than just that. I'll update and turn that snippet of yours into a module. But to be honest: jQ is a module. UI interactions can be dealt with in the callback, without cluttering the global namespace. Personally, I wouldn't bother with my own, external module

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Ah, then that is my bad. Obviously I'm a little confused, so I'll just do additional research on my end, instead of tying up your time. Thanks again!

Comment: @Josh: no need, provided an example, and added a link that provides a bit more info on the module pattern

Answer (score 1):

This has the same behavior as your code:

```
var Application = (function() {
    var app = {
        MemberVar1: null,
        MemberVar2: null,
        GetMemberVars: function() { /* ... */},
        Initialize: function() {
            this.MemberVar1 = 'Foo';
            this.MemberVar2 = 'Bar';
            console.log('Initializing..');
            this.getMemberVars();
        }
    };
    $(function() {app.Initialize();});
    return app;
}());
```

But there's a good chance that you don't really want that `Initialize` function hanging around.  So this would simplify it:

```
var Application = (function() {
    var app = {
        MemberVar1: null,
        MemberVar2: null,
        GetMemberVars: function() { /* ... */}
    };
    $(function() {
        app.MemberVar1 = 'Foo';
        app.MemberVar2 = 'Bar';
        console.log('Initializing..');
        app.getMemberVars();
    });
    return app;
}());
```

And unless you're actually worried about code trying to access `Application.MemberVar1`, etc before jQuery's `document.ready` event, you can simplify it further to this:

```
var Application = (function() {
    var app = {
        GetMemberVars: function() { /* ... */}
    };
    $(function() {
        app.MemberVar1 = 'Foo';
        app.MemberVar2 = 'Bar';
        console.log('Initializing..');
        app.getMemberVars();
    });
    return app;
}());
```

I'm assuming that defining those `MemberVar`s took some real work, and were not simple strings as in the example.  If that's not the case, then I would switch this last to

```
var Application = (function() {
    var app = {
        MemberVar1: 'Foo';
        MemberVar2: 'Bar';
        GetMemberVars: function() { /* ... */}
    };
    $(function() {
        console.log('Initializing..');
        app.getMemberVars();
    });
    return app;
}());
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use prototype if you are going to use only one instance of some object.

In this case it's pretty clear the Application object is something unique and the author didn't intend there were going to be any additional copies of Application created.

Talking about style... that capital camel case looks ugly. The common agreement is to use CapitalCamelCase only for object constructors. I personally think it's ok to use for unique objects with logic too (Application). But using it for function names and variables should be avoided.

Talking about patterns... it's close to Singleton pattern. But don't think too much about it. All those OOP patterns from Java world lose part of their appeal in JS world. Some of them disintegrate completely. Concentrate on JS ways of solving problems.

Comment: And you! Thank you as well.

Comment: Thank you too. :) When I finished writing the answer I had seen the other one which was much more thorough. That made me think my answer didn't add anything to conversation. I'm glad that's not true.